# LDAP Authentication not working with Online LDAP Test Server

Tags: sockets, ldap

I am using the below configuration to connect to [Online LDAP Test Server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/)

```
  <className>com.worklight.core.auth.ext.LdapLoginModule</className>
        <parameter name="ldapProviderUrl" value="ldap://forumsys.com:389"/>
        <parameter name="ldapTimeoutMs" value="2000"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityAuthentication" value="simple"/>
        <parameter name="validationType" value="searchPattern"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSecurityPrincipalPattern" value="uid={username},ou=mathematicians,dc=example,dc=com"/>
        <parameter name="ldapSearchFilterPattern" value="(uid={username})"/>     
        <parameter name="ldapSearchBase" value="dc=example,dc=com"/>
```

But i am getting

> "FWLSE4014W: LdapLoginModule authentication failed. Reason 'javax.naming.CommunicationException: forumsys.com:389 [Root exception is java.net.SocketTimeoutException: connect timed out]" error.

Is there anything wrong with the settings ?

Answer (score 1):

that server is pretty old and the LDAP service is no longer active

Answer (score 0):

This exception is not unique to MobileFirst and so I remove this information from the question.

See here: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21599197.
I suggest that you will follow the same solution steps, which are to verify that you are attempting to correctly connect to your LDAP server.

> Recommended but optional: Download a third-party tool (such as the ldapsearch tool) that can verify your server(s) are able to communicate with the LDAP server independent of the Portal ConfigEngine configuration task. Run the tool directly from the Portal server (and Deployment Manager if clustered) to verify all servers can communicate with the LDAP server.
>
> In this particular use case, a network firewall was configured to block all traffic to the LDAP server except from IP addresses that were explicitly whitelisted / permitted to connect. The primary Portal server had been configured in the network firewall to communicate with the LDAP server, but the Deployment Manager had not been configured. Adding the Deployment Manager IP address to the firewall rules allowed the configuration task to complete successfully.

Answer (score 0):

I recently used [ForumSys LDAP Test server](http://www.forumsys.com/tutorials/integration-how-to/ldap/online-ldap-test-server/) mentioned using **KeyCloak** successfully:
You can find all the configuration [here](https://codehumsafar.wordpress.com/2018/09/28/keycloak-user-federation-using-forumsys-online-ldap-test-server/).

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for an easily configurable dockerized test LDAP authentication server.
try

> https://hub.docker.com/r/upekshejay/simple-ldap-test-server

Answer (score 0):

I used [ForumSys LDAP Test Server](https://www.forumsys.com/2022/05/10/online-ldap-test-server/)
, here is fully tested sample used to check if a user is already inside an active directory.

```
public class ActiveDirectoryManagerTwo {

final static String domainTree = "dc=example,dc=com";

public static void main(String[] args) {

    System.out.println(isInsideActiveDirectory("tesla"));

}

public static String isInsideActiveDirectory(String userName) {

    String isFound = "NO";
    String rootDN = "cn=read-only-admin,dc=example,dc=com";
    String rootPWD = "password";

    Hashtable<String, String> environment = new Hashtable<String, String>();
    environment.put(Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY, "com.sun.jndi.ldap.LdapCtxFactory");
    environment.put(Context.PROVIDER_URL, "ldap://ldap.forumsys.com :389");

    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_AUTHENTICATION, "simple");
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_PRINCIPAL, rootDN);
    environment.put(Context.SECURITY_CREDENTIALS, rootPWD);

    DirContext dirContext = null;
    NamingEnumeration<?> results = null;

    try {
        System.out.println("inside try");
        dirContext = new InitialDirContext(environment);
        SearchControls controls = new SearchControls();
        controls.setSearchScope(SearchControls.SUBTREE_SCOPE);
        String filter = "(&(uid=" + userName + "))";
        results = dirContext.search(domainTree, filter, controls);
        if (results.hasMore()) {
            isFound = "YES";
        } else {
        }

    } catch (NamingException e) {
        System.out.println("inside catch");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        if (results != null) {
            try {
                results.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }

        if (dirContext != null) {
            try {
                dirContext.close();
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
    return isFound;
}
```

}